# Как решить проблему с роутингом в Symfony 3?

Tags: php, symfony3

Начал изучать симфони и столкнулся с такой проблемой: Есть метод, с роутингом "`/show`", и есть метод с "`/show/{id}`".
Можно их как-то объединить?

И еще такое странное поведение: "`/show`" и "`/show/`" почему-то 2 разных роутинга. Т.е. если указано просто `show`, то переход на `show/` выдает 404 ошибку. Как это исправить?

До этого юзал Codeigniter. Там с роутингом все проще.

Comment: На счет последнего слеша, можете настроить ваш веб сервер на редирект на страницу со слешом/без слеша.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете объединить два пути, указав в директкиве `_defaults: { id: 1 }`

```
# app/config/routing.yml
blog:
    path:      /blog/{page}
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Blog:index, page: 1 }
```

[источник](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#required-and-optional-placeholders)

Страницы с путями `/show` и `/show/` - разные пути, так что лучше всего настройте редирект на ссылки со слэшом на конце, или наоборот, как решите.

В принципе вы можете воспользоваться методом, который есть в `Symfony CookBook`

**1. Создайте контроллер:**

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/RedirectingController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class RedirectingController extends Controller
{
    public function removeTrailingSlashAction(Request $request)
    {
        $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();
        $requestUri = $request->getRequestUri();

        $url = str_replace($pathInfo, rtrim($pathInfo, ' /'), $requestUri);

        return $this->redirect($url, 301);
    }
}
```

**Добавьте в самый конец списка роутов новый роут:**

```
    remove_trailing_slash:
        path: /{url}
        defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Redirecting:removeTrailingSlash }
        requirements:
            url: .*/$
        methods: [GET]
```

[источник](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html)